# Input Field to Laravel save: store datetime when adding just the date

Tags: php, sql, laravel, function, datetime

Goal:

- have two columns (datetime) save an input field that only takes in date

I would like the start date to save `11/11/2021 00:00:00` and the end date `11/12/2021 23:59:59` (only the date can be changed) from a text field that a user can only place a date in the text field:

```
<div class="row" id="custom_date">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">From:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="date" id="custom_start_datetime" name="custom_start_datetime">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">To:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="date" id="custom_end_datetime" name="custom_end_datetime">
  </div>
 </div>
```

snippet of my store function:

```
            $shift->effective_start_datetime = $request_add->input('effective_start_datetime'); 
            $shift->effective_end_datetime = $request_add->input('effective_end_datetime');
```

the code above gives an error because the row is in `timestamp without time zone` and it gets the data from the text fields that only takes in the date and no time.

What can I change in my function code to have the date save but in the h/m/s format it could have `00:00:00` for the `start_datetime` and `23:59:59` `end_datetime` automatically?

for example, if I input in the two text fields `08/11/2021` and `08/13/2021` it will be saved as: `08/11/2021 00:00:00` and `08/13/2021 23:59:59`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Carbon class to manipulate your dates, so, if you want to put the time, you can use `parse` method and use `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` methods.

Example:

```php
$startDate = Carbon::parse($firstDate)->startOfDay();  // Will return a Carbon Instance at 00:00:00
$endDate = Carbon::parse($secondDate)->endOfDay();  // Will return a Carbon Instance at 23:59:59
```

These methods will solve your problem, and if you need a time zone, you can use `toISOString` method after `startOfDay` and `endOfDay`, that is the default format of API response.

```
$endDate = Carbon::parse($secondDate)->endOfDay()->toISOString();  // 2021-08-12T23:21:54.788279Z
```

Comment: thanks for this, did not know the `Carbon::parse` before

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbon to parse and manipulate your dates before inserting to database. For end date we need a little bit hack, we will `add 1 day` and `subtract 1 second` so we can have it easily.

```php
$startDate = Carbon::parse($request_add->input('effective_start_datetime'));
$endDate = Carbon::parse($request_add->input('effective_end_datetime'))->addDay()->subSecond();

$shift->effective_start_datetime = $startDate;
$shift->effective_end_datetime = $endDate;
```